# Apply background-color to each element

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have html code:

```
<div class="color-block">
    <h6 class="elliot-bold">Color</h6>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#!">#ff0142;</a></li>
        <li><a href="#!">#ff8500;</a></li>
        <li><a href="#!">#ffde00;</a></li>
        <li><a href="#!">#96bc05;</a></li>
        <li style="margin-right: 0px;"><a href="#!">#2cb8db;</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And I need to apply background-color depending on

```
<a href="#!">#96bc05;</a>
```

value dynamically.
What I'm trying is to use jQuery each function something like this:

```
$('.color-block ul li a').each(function(){
     var color = $(this).html();
     $(this).css('background-color', color)
})
```

It's not working and I can't find example how to realize this.

Comment: I think its working https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/121/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$(this).css('background-color', color.replace(";",""));
```

Answer (score 1):

remove semicolon from html or use replace in jquery.

```js
$('.color-block ul li a').each(function(){
       var color = $(this).text()
       console.log(color)
       $(this).css('background-color',color)
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="color-block">
    <h6 class="elliot-bold">Color</h6>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#!">#ff0142</a></li>
        <li><a href="#!">#ff8500</a></li>
        <li><a href="#!">#ffde00</a></li>
        <li><a href="#!">#96bc05</a></li>
        <li style="margin-right: 0px;"><a href="#!">#2cb8db;</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

```js
$('.color-block ul li a').each(function(){
       var color = $(this).text()
       console.log(color)
       $(this).css('background-color',color.replace(";",""))
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="color-block">
    <h6 class="elliot-bold">Color</h6>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#!">#ff0142;</a></li>
        <li><a href="#!">#ff8500;</a></li>
        <li><a href="#!">#ffde00;</a></li>
        <li><a href="#!">#96bc05;</a></li>
        <li style="margin-right: 0px;"><a href="#!">#2cb8db;</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```